# how to update record in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

this is the code for edit

```
function edit($id){

    if(!empty($this->data)) {
        if($this->Article->save($this->data)) {
            pr($this->Article);
            $this->Session->setFlash("Article Saved!");
            $this->redirect('/articles/view');        
            }    
    }
    else    
        $this->data = $this->Article->findByArticleId($id);

}
```

and for the view

```
<?php 
echo $form->create('Article', array('type' => 'post','action'=>'edit')); 
?>

<table>
<tr><td>Edit Article</td></tr>
<tr><td>Title: </td><td><?php echo $form->text('article_title',array('label'=>false,'type'=>'text','size'=>50)); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Text: </td><td><?php echo $form->textarea('article_text',array('label'=>false,'class'=>'ckeditor','columns'=>100,'row'=>8,'width'=>100));?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Published: </td><td><?php echo $form->radio('article_published',array('1'=>'Yes','0'=>'No'),array('legend'=>false));?></td></tr>
</table>
<?php echo $form->end('Save'); ?>
```

the problem is it always adds a new record instead of updating the current record. how can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why a new record is inserted is that CakePHP method doesn't know the ID of the record you're editing. Basically, when data passed to the `save()` method does not contain the record ID or the ID does not exist in the table, `save()` will insert a new record instead of updating an existing one.

The usual way of fixing this would be adding `echo $form->input('id');` to the form. This will add a hidden field with the ID of the record being edited to the form. At this point enabling the [security component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) would be a good idea as it will help you prevent tampering with form data.

Comment: I have the same problem and lose many hairs with it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: this is the real problem with cakephp (no real documentation).

http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelsave